# How to solve the system of non-linear equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

$$\begin{cases} 3x^2 -3y =0 \\ 3y^2 - 3x = 0 \end{cases}$$

I really forgot how to solve this since my childhood, apperently it is not linear equations and Gauss' method cant'be applied

Comment: are you familiar with complex numbers? There are two real and two complex solutions for $x$, likewise for $y$

Comment: From the symmetry of the equations, you know that, for $x,y\in\mathbb R$,  $x=y$. It should be easy to solve from there.

Comment: Have you taken time, first, to search "system of two non-linear equations in two variables", and/or other combinations?  Here? Google?

Comment: Seems, J.Doe, that you've already mastered mathjax.  Hmm, and you just joined today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the first equation we get $$y=x^2$$ plugging this in the second equation we obtain
$$x^4-x=0$$ and from here we obtain $$x(x^3-1)=0$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 3 and rearrange to see that the system is equivalent to the easier-looking:
\begin{cases} y = x^2 \\ x = y^2 \end{cases}
Now substituting $x=y^2$ into $y=x^2$ gives you:
$$y=y^4 \iff y = 0 \; \vee y = 1$$
The corresponding $x$-values are identical.

If you draw the graphs of the two (easy) parabolas, you can easily find (or confirm) the solutions graphically.

Comment: Over the complex numbers there are two more solutions...

Comment: @TMM Yes, but without context (no complex tag and real nor complex explicitly mentioned) and with the choice of variables x and y, it seemed safe to assume working over the reals. If not, OP can clarify of course.

Answer (score 0):

If $x,y \in \mathbb R$

From the equation, we know $x >=0$, and $y>=0$
$$y=x^2,x=y^2$$
$$x^4-x=x(x^3-1)=0$$

Thus $(x = 0, y=0)$, or $(x = 1, y=1)$

**If we allow complex numbers**:
$$y=x^2,x=y^2$$
$$x^4-x=x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=x(x-1)(x-\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2})(x-\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2})=0$$

Thus $(x=0,y=0), (x=1, y=1), (x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}, y=\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}),(x=\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2},y=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2})$

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can also see the solutions geometrically.

The graph of the first equation (which is equivalent to $y=x^2$) is a parabola with vertex at the origin and symmetric about the positive $y$-axis.

The graph of the second equation (which is equivalent to $x=y^2$) is a parabola with vertex at the origin and symmetric about the positive $x$-axis.

These graphs intersect exactly at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, so these points are the only solutions to the system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

We have $x^2-y^2+x-y=0$ or $(x-y)(x+y+1)=0$,

which gives $x=y$ and $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$

or $x+y+1=0$, which with $x^2-y=0$ gives $x^2+x+1=0$, which is impossible.

Comment: Why would it follow that $x=y$ from your first equation? You're tossing away half the information you have when you add the equations. (The function $f(x) = x^2+x$ is not injective, so $f(x) = f(y)$ has several non-trivial solutions.)